# Android: ExpandableListView ChildClickListener not working after list scroll

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have created a `ExpandableListView` Search Activity which shows 3 groups - *Tracks, Artists, Albums*.
As the user types text in `EditText`, the corresponding search results are displayed in ExpandableListView.

**PROBLEM:**
When the user clicks on any child item, I want to perform some operation. At first this function is working fine, but when I scroll the list up or down, the `OnChildClickListener` stops working. And no child gets selected on click.

Is this a problem with the view update & positions?

NOTE: I'm using `BaseExpandableListAdapter`

Here is the code: (I've pasted what I've thought was necessary. Plz let me know if other part is required):

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.search);

            etSearchBar = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSearchBar);
            etSearchBar.addTextChangedListener(this);

            lvExpSearchResult = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExpSearchResult);
            lvExpSearchResult.setGroupIndicator(null);
            lvExpSearchResult.setChildIndicator(null);
            lvExpSearchResult.setOnTouchListener(this);
            lvExpSearchResult.setOnChildClickListener(this);
        }

    @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View view, int groupPosition,
                int childPosition, long id) {
            lvExpSearchResult.smoothScrollToPosition(groupPosition);
            Toast.makeText(SearchActivity.this, group[groupPosition], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Toast.makeText(SearchActivity.this, children[groupPosition][childPosition], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        }

@Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if (s.length() > 0) {
            group = new String[] { "Tracks", "Albums", "Artists" };
            ArrayList<String> result = null;

            result = getQueryResult(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
            result = new Utilities().removeDuplicatesAL(result);
            String[] tracks = result.toArray(new String[result.size()]);

            result = getQueryResult(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM);
            result = new Utilities().removeDuplicatesAL(result);
            String[] albums = result.toArray(new String[result.size()]);

            result = getQueryResult(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
            result = new Utilities().removeDuplicatesAL(result);
            String[] artists = result.toArray(new String[result.size()]);

            children = new String[][] { tracks, albums, artists };

            adapter = new SearchAdapter(this, group, children);
        } else {
            adapter = new SearchAdapter(this, new String[0], new String[0][0]);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        lvExpSearchResult.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

// BaseExpandableListAdapter code - getGroupView & getChildView
@Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView childRow = (TextView) convertView;
        if (childRow == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            try {
                childRow = (TextView) inflator.inflate(
                        android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, null);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(context, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
        childRow.setText(children[groupPosition][childPosition]);
        return childRow;
    }

@Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView headerRow = (TextView) convertView;
        if (headerRow == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            headerRow = (TextView) inflator.inflate(
                    android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, null);
        }
        headerRow.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        headerRow.setText(group[groupPosition]);

        ExpandableListView eLV = (ExpandableListView)parent;
        eLV.expandGroup(groupPosition);

        return headerRow;
    }
```

Comment: What happens when you typing text in EditText? Maybe you initialize your list every time text changed? Try to use custom ExpandableList and override getChildView and set click listener on it

Comment: yes, everytime the user types a new list is passed to a custom `BaseExpandableListAdapter` and the results are updated. I have added a `addTextChangeListener` on `EditText` which calls the adapter & displays the result. Code updated.

Comment: Try to set onClickListener on childView in getChildView method of your adapter like this https://github.com/gobozov/myshows/blob/master/src/ru/myshows/fragments/EpisodesFragment.java

Comment: I'll keep this in mind..thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think your child method problem and just this code implement and try this out,

```
    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return ;
        // false = default and do not get click 
        // true = get the focus of child and got the click
    }
```